# How to add pagination to custom collection in admin tab content

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I have added a custom tab in customer admin view.

My tab class content is :

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('tab/tab.phtml');
    }
}
```

And in `tab.phtml` I have custom collection and want to add pagination.

How to add pagination for custom collection here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution :

I created a `grid.php` in my custom module for custom collection and add grid in `tab.phtml` as below :

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('custom/adminhtml_path_grid')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1: Controller**,
First in our `IndexController` we will simply load the layout and render it.

```
<?php
class Excellence_Collection_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Step2: Layout**,
In our module layout file, i.e `collection.xml` this is the code to put

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <collection_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="collection/collection" name="collection" template="collection/collection.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </collection_index_index>
</layout>
```

**Step3: Block**,
Next we will create our block `collection/collection` where the main code for paging goes.

```
<?php
class Excellence_Collection_Block_Collection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('collection/collection')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code we have created a block for the pager and set our collection in it.
**Step4: phtml file**,
Next in our `collection.phtml` file we need to put in this code

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Collection') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($collection->getSize()): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-custom-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('ID #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Title') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Created') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($collection as $_obj): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_obj->getCollectionId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_obj->getTitle(); ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_obj->getCreatedTime()) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-custom-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('The collection is empty.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is all that is required, now the paging should show up on your collection.

Showing Toolbar on Custom Collection
Now we will add a toolbar to our custom collection, i.e will add sorting and view modes. Here is the end result of the code

[image]

Comment: I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: ok sure.........let me know if you have any issue with that.

Comment: Hello, I tried but it is not working, this is working in frontend template but as I said I have to implement it is in admin panel in customer section where I added a custom tab.